# ToolStripComboBoxItem arrow not paint desired color (VS.Net 2010, WinForms)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am rendering a toolstrip with a CustomRenderer that inherits from ToolStripProfessionalRenderer. The concept is that I want the color of the arrow of the toolstrip items to be white in all cases except selection. When it is selected the color should be black. In my code below all arrows are painted accordingly except the ToolStripComboBox where the color of the arrow always remains the same; the default one. How to sort it out?

Hope I don't need to write the whole class but only the relevant fragment. So I uploaded the OnRenderArrow method only.

```
Friend Class CustomRenderer
    Inherits ToolStripProfessionalRenderer

    Sub New()

    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnRenderArrow(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripArrowRenderEventArgs)
        If e.Item.Pressed Then
            e.ArrowColor = Color.White
        ElseIf e.Item.Selected Then
            e.ArrowColor = SystemColors.ControlText
        Else
            e.ArrowColor = Color.White
        End If

        MyBase.OnRenderArrow(e)
    End Sub
End Class
```

To render the toolstrip with the pertinent class:

```
MyToolStrip.Renderer = New CustomRenderer
```

Answer (score 0):

ToolStripComboBox is a regular combobox that is hosted in ToolStripControlHost. ToolStripItem arrows is as mentioned the menu children indicators and is not related to that. You may be able to utilize the code to custom paint ComboBox here: [Painting right arrow in ToolStripComboBox](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/d846c71b-d405-495f-9b6d-8d0b361a0aac/)